# MySQL Integer Column with Unique values in it, however default value is 2( not NULL) ? Is it Possible?

Tags: mysql

I want a table with an integer column, that must be filled with a default value 1111 when no input is received. But if we receive input it should be filled and I want it to be UNIQUE : there cannot be two entries of the same number(except default value 111). Ex :-

[image]

I know we can achieve the objective if our default value is NULL but here in my case I need to have a integer default value and unique check in all other integer added.

Please guide me if this can be achieved or not ?

Comment: what is wrong with NULL you can always replace it in queries with 1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UNIQUE KEY can't hold the value 1111 multiple times.

So use `NULL` and replace it in the queries

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1(col1 int,col2 int UNIQUe )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1,NULL),(2,1)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'tab1.col2'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT col1,IFNULL(col2,1111) FROm tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | IFNULL(col2,1111)
> ---: | ----------------:
>    1 |              1111
>    2 |                 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2cb384c1e200564f99860514566245c9)*

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could not use `unique` with  default value. because the point of unique in MySql is preventing duplicates in column. Which making conflicts in that logic.
You must handle the duplication before sending the insert query to DB (in Backend) or you may use techniques other than `unique` like:

- `INSERT IGNORE`: will insert rows in the same way as INSERT, but with the exception that it will ignore rows with duplicate values and continue execution without creating an error. Any row that contains a duplicate value will not be inserted.
- `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`: will insert any non-duplicate rows as normal. However, when it encounters a duplicate row, it will perform an UPDATE on the original row.
- `REPLACE`: works the same as INSERT, except that when it encounters a duplicate row, it deletes the original row and then continues with the insert. Any row with a duplicate unique index value will replace the row that originally contained the value.